# Notifying business users on successful build

Tags: mercurial, notifications, teamcity

We have a current set up on `TeamCity` that notifiers it's users after a build (and for us a release).

This happens on success or failure and inside the email is a list of the latest commits since the last build. When the next successful build occurs after a failure, there is nothing in the commit list since TC agrees to itself this info has already gone out.

The problem is, we really only want to notify certain (business) people on successful build, and show all commits since the last successful build.

I'm sure this is possible with some custom task, using the Hg api etc, I'm just wondering if there is anything customizable inside the TC box?

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but one workaround would be to create a new configuration called 'Build Project xxx Successful'. Ensure the VCS settings are configured to be attached to your Mercurial repo, but don't add any build steps. Add a build trigger to be on successful build of your main build configuration. Add the email notification rules to the new build configuration instead of the old one. As the build will only run when there is a successful build, it will include all of the commits which have gone in since the last successful build.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this rather easily

1. Create a second build configuration.
2. Add a snapshot dependency to your build project from the new project.
3. In the Version control settings of the new project make sure "Show changes from snapshot dependencies is selected.
4. Create a "Finished Build Trigger" in the new project.
5. Create a user that represents your business mailing list.
6. Configure this user to be notified when the new project is executed.

You can leave out the trigger is you want to manually send this notifications, See [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Customizing+Notifications) if you want to customize the email.